# Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /temp could not be mounted (still need help)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am trying to change a GRUB2 boot entry and can not seem to edit or save the file after entering `sudo vi /etc/grub.d/10_lupin` into terminal.

I am having the same problem as a few others with the way Ubuntu 14.04 boots and found instructions to fix the problem by changing this line:

```
linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${LINUX_HOST_DEVICE} loop=${loop_file_relative} ro ${args}
```

to this:

```
linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${LINUX_HOST_DEVICE} loop=${loop_file_relative} rw ${args}
```

Please be patient with me, I don't know what the heck I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line in the Terminal:    `sudo nano /etc/grub.d/10_lupin`

As I'm not that familiar with using Vi to edit text, Nano was a little easier for me to edit. just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to write the file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit when you're finish with it, and when you're back in the terminal, enter    `sudo update-grub`